# Start/stop gif on mouseover and mouseout

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to begin a GIF animation when the visitor hovers the image, and I have actually done that part with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".lazy[title='img-static']").hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "https://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/img-static.png");
  }, function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "https://www.webco.dk/wp-content/uploads/img-animation.gif");
  });
});
```

It changes the image from the static PNG to the animating GIF, however I need it to switch back to the static when the mouse leaves.

Also I heard that I should have the GIF preload, how would you do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your code should be doing what you describe, although note that the logic is backwards. The first function in `hover` is the 'over' state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with mouseenter()/mouseleave() instead, something like:

```
$(".lazy[title='img-static']").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "https://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/img-static.png");
});
$(".lazy[title='img-static']").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "https://www.webco.dk/wp-content/uploads/img-animation.gif");
});
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly, when I run it in the console. My issue now seems to be that the code runs before the element is actually showing.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean :) What happens when the page has been loaded ?

Comment: The image is not loaded before the code is executed, leading to the code not having its effect. Preferably the code should be run when the image is loaded, but I can't really figure out how to do that. I might just put a timer on it.

Comment: can you post the code with the image? Do you originally output the gif first or the png or just image with empty src attr ?